# Resolve imports in chrome injected content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vite, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am currently working on a Chrome extension and I have come across a challenge that I'm seeking assistance with.

I have a content script that's in charge of establishing a connection with a WebSocket server. Once this connection is successfully set up, the background script utilizes the chrome.scripting.executeScript method to inject another content script into main environment.

```
import { ui } from "./ui";

(() => {
    function inject(tabId: number, func: (...args: Array<any>) => any, ...args: Array<any>) {
        return new Promise<boolean>((r) => {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                {
                    target: { tabId },
                    args: [...args],
                    world: "MAIN",
                    injectImmediately: true,
                    func: func,
                }, 
                () => {
                    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                        return r(false);
                    }
                    return r(true);
                }
            );
        });
    }

    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(async (connection) => {
        if (connection.name === "connect") {
            await inject(connection.sender.tab.id!, ui, chrome.runtime.id);
        }
    });
})();
```

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { App } from "ui/App.tsx";

function ui(id: string) {
    const connection = chrome.runtime.connect(id, { name: "ui" });
    // handling connection related stuff
    // ...
    
    let root: App | null = null;

    function render() {
        if (!document.head || !document.body) {
            setTimeout(() => render(), 100);
            return;
        }

        if (!root) {
            const element = document.createElement("div");
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            root = createRoot(element);
        }
        root.render(<App/>);
    }

    render();
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that I am attempting to render a React component in injected content script but React code appears to be located outside of the injected function so I got error that React's render function is not defined.

I also would like to add that I'm using Vite in this project and that content script must be bundled along with service worker.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Comment: 1) Remove `world` parameter and don't use `MAIN` world unless absolutely necessary as it's highly unsafe. 2) To use variables/functions from a module or a closed scope you'll need to assign them to `window` e.g. `window.foo = function(){.....}` and then call it as `foo()` or `window.foo()`

Comment: Where I should declare that? I tried to place it in connect content script, injected content script and service worker but anywhere I put that it still is not working. @wOxxOm

Comment: The thing you call "injected content script" runs in the unsafe MAIN world so it can't access anything from your other safe content scripts, which is why I said not to use the MAIN world.